# C Language Fixed Point Math

Tags: c, fixed-point

I am familiar with the Arduino programming tools but have relatively small experience with embedded programming. When using decimal numbers in the Arduino I never had any issues, so when I recently started playing around with TI's Launchpad F28069M(TMS320F28069M Chip), I was surprised that my math was not yielding my expected results. While doing research, I realized that the TI chip has a fixed point processor which may explain why my decimals are being truncated to 0. (See brief code example)

My questions are the following:

1. How should I declare decimal numbers in my code?
2. Should I use TI's IQ math?
3. Why was I able to declare and perform math functions with decimal numbers in the Arduino without any issue?

My Code

```
Uint16 A;

main()
{
    A = .25;
}
```

Result from Expression Window in TI's CCS:
[Expression Window CCS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJIFt.png)

[image: Expression Window CCS]

Comment: `Uint16` is a 16 bits unsigned integer ( no decimals...), so what is not clear???....

Comment: You have *a lot* of misconceptions.

Comment: Uint16 is not a fixed-point type in the common sense.

Comment: You are trying to put a 0.25 (floating point) into an 16 bit integer, 025 simply gets rounded to 0 and you get 0 in `A` which is expected.

Comment: I feel bad because this question get downvoted simply because people don't understand fixed point. Fixed point numbers are integers to machines and are usually `typedef` as existing integer types. For beginners I recommend TI's IQMath library. As you get more informed you can look for IQMath source code and use some lower level functions. The IQMath API is not perfect, e.g. IQ_N_div function does not handle the case when the input and outputs are different Q but the lower level implementation does.

Comment: I do appreciate the feedback !! I was scratching my head over this issue and now I realize that I was using an integer instead of float . Now my code runs fine !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this code instead:

```
float A;

main()
{
    A = .25;
}
```